# Unable to recreate mysql table after dropping due to error 150 (foreign key constraint)!

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

This is not a duplicate as I saw all the other posts and found no answers to this particular case. My steps:

1. Created two tables and added a foreign key from table 2 to table 1
2. Dropped tbale 1 and then table 2
3. Changed the name of the primary key field (and its type) in table 1 and recreated both
4. On adding foreign key, I got the error
5. HOWEVER, I then ran a `SHOW CREATE TABLE Table2` (and Table1) and neither one shows a name of the foreign key for me to delete!

Without that name, I am unable to drop the foreign key (I added it without specifying a name orginally and none is shown now). What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the name of foreign key. If it was created without name, then name will be auto generated.

Try these queries to get the FK names:

```
SELECT
  constraint_name
FROM
information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
constraint_schema = <'db_name'> AND table_name = <'table_name'>;


SELECT *
FROM
information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
constraint_schema = <'db_name'> AND table_name = <'table_name'> AND   
referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: After use `ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP INDEX <fk_name>` to drop foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

In the second step do you change the column type of foreign key field? Must be the same of primary key.

In addiction, you have to update SQL statement for foreign key constraint adding new column names.